# Displaying Autocomplete in div using jQuery, PHP

Tags: php, html, autocomplete

I have 2 pages

> index.php and function.php

on page `

> index.php

` there is this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#skill").autocomplete("get_list.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="input-box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

> and on page function.php

```
<?php 
$form = '
<div name="input" class="input_box" id="input">
<form action="function.php" target="iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
....
<div style="padding-right: 14px;">

<input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" />

</div>
 ...
</form>
</div>
    ';
?>
```

> on page index.php when i put this div 
>   the page displays form from page function.php, but autocomplete
>   functions are not working.
>
> but when i put this input   on page index.php autocomplete works,

**how to make autocomplete work on this div  from page *function.php***

Comment: I want to make autocomplete "<input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" />" to work on the page function.php, but it doesn't go. It works only on index.php. I am trying to find a solution to make autocomplete work through the <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" />

Answer (score 0):

why are you putting all your HTML codes in a variable?

if you're trying to include the form from another page just include the form without the use a of variable.

```
 <div class="input-box">
   <?php include("function.php");?>
 </div>
```

and function.php as

```
 <div name="input" class="input_box" id="input">
 <form action="function.php" target="iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
 ....
 <div style="padding-right: 14px;">

 <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" />

 </div>
  ...
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: how are you displaying the function.php page on your index page? 
Please be more specific on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to make autocomplete "<input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" />" to work on the page function.php, but it doesn't go. It works only on index.php. I am trying to find a solution to make autocomplete work through the  <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" />